# Django - Inline Object's overrided method not called

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class ServiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Service

class PlanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ServiceInline]

class ServiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):   
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        if not instance.created_at and not instance.modified_at:
           instance.created_by = request.user
        instance.modified_by = request.user
        instance.save()        
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

I have overrided the `save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):` method of Service class in it's admin class. But this overrided method is not getting called when a Service object added via Inline (Plan's page). Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post code of how you override that save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `save_model` function in the admin, which I don’t think is going to work, what about the following:

```
class PlanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.last_updated_by = request.user
        instance.save()

class Service(models.Model):
    # ...
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_by = self.plan.last_updated_by
        super(Service, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: @sneenu Thanks for your help. But, this answer seems to be not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Siva I’ve rewritten the answer, which will hopefully help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer specific to your use case, but you might be able to work around your problem using `post_save` signal: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/signals/#post-save

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is move that save_model method into the ServiceInline class.  The ServiceInline, in this case, is your Admin class for the Service.